# Can't get empty substring when no token found in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I am trying to get a substring after the token "-" in bash

I have following function:

```
STR="abc-def"
END=`echo $STR | cut -d "-" -f2`
echo $END # prints def (OK)

STR="abc"
END=`echo $STR | cut -d "-" -f2`
echo $END # prints abc (ERROR)

STR="abc-abc"
END=`echo $STR | cut -d "-" -f2`
echo $END # prints abc (OK)
```

How can I fix it so that, when I don't find the "-" I get END=""?

Comment: Just for completeness: If `STR=-def`, you want to have `END` set to `def`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: In my originall solution, I assumed by mistake that `END´ should keep the leading hyphen, and I just noticed that this is not the case. I have now updated my solution, and the new version became a bit simpler:

No need to spawn a child process here. Basically you can do a

```
END=${STR#*-}
```

The glob pattern after `#` removes everything up to the first `-`. This still leaves the problem open, that if `STR` does not contain a hypen, you get the original string back, not the empty string.

Since you have tagged your question as *bash* and *shell*, I will suggest solutions for both.

In bash, you can simply do a

```
if [[ $STR == *-* ]]
then
  END="${STR#*-}"
else
  END=
fi
```

Since `[[` is not an external command, this also does not need a sub-process.

In POSIX shell, I would do a

```
END="${STR#*-}" # Remove up to (including) hyphen
if [ "$END" = "$STR" ]
then
  # We did not have a hyphen
  END=
fi
```

This does spawn one subprocess (the `[`), so it's more costly than the bash version.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your string to check if it contains the separator character at all:

```
[[ "${STR}" == *"-"* ]] && END=$(echo $STR | cut -d "-" -f2) || END = ""
```

If You prefer the (in this case not so cryptic) regexp aproach:

```
[[ "${STR}" =~ "-" ]] && END=$(echo $STR | cut -d "-" -f2) || END = ""
```

Comment: `STR="abc-def"; set -f: IFS=-; set -- $STR; END="$2";`

Comment: Aside from the typo after `-f`  (colon vs. semicolon), this would not give correct result for STR starting with a hyphen. Othewise clever idea!

Answer (score -1):

Change '-' to ' '

```
STR=${STR//-/' '}
```

Convert STR to an array

```
STR=( $STR )
```

Assign 2-nd item to END

```
END=${STR[1]}
```

If 2-nd item exist END will be 'def' if not then END will be empty. Oneliner

```
STR="abc-def"; STR=( ${STR//-/' '} ); END=${STR[1]}; echo $END
```

And in case of spaces in left\right or both sides, change of IFS can help

```
IFS=-; STR='ab x-de f'; ARR=( $STR ); END=${ARR[1]}; echo $END
```

Or you can convert spaces firs and in the end convert tham back

```
STR='ab x-de f'; STR=${STR//' '/_SPACE_}; STR=${STR//-/' '}; ARR=( $STR ); END=${ARR[1]}; echo ${END//_SPACE_/' '}
```

Comment: While I did not downvote it, your approach would faile for `STR='ab    x-def'`

Comment: Add variant with IFS change